# SQL Parameter value is getting truncated

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have the following code which simply executes a stored procedure which accepts 1 parameter.

```vb
Public Function GetData(ByVal Faccode As String, Optional ByRef s As String = "") As DataSet

    Dim params As SqlParameter() = {New SqlParameter("@aFacilityCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Input)}

    ' Set the value
    params(0).Value = "SW29" 'Faccode

    Try
        Dim DSet As DataSet = RunProcedure("usp_FL_GetAllData", params, "ContactData")
        Return DSet
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function

Protected Overloads Function RunProcedure( _
  ByVal storedProcName As String, _
  ByVal parameters As IDataParameter(), _
  ByVal tableName As String) _
  As DataSet

  Dim dataSet As New dataSet

  Try
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim sqlDA As New SqlDataAdapter
    sqlDA.SelectCommand = BuildQueryCommand(storedProcName, parameters)
    sqlDA.Fill(dataSet, tableName)

    Return dataSet
  Catch ex As Exception
    Return Nothing
  Finally
    If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
      myConnection.Close()
    End If
  End Try
End Function

Private Function BuildQueryCommand( _
  ByVal storedProcName As String, _
  ByVal parameters As IDataParameter()) _
  As SqlCommand

  Dim command As New SqlCommand(storedProcName, myConnection)
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

  Dim parameter As SqlParameter
  For Each parameter In parameters
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
  Next

  Return command

End Function
```

The SQL procedure is defined like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_FL_GetAllData]
(
   @aFacilityCode VARCHAR(10)
)
```

When I run the software, SQL Profiler shows this call is being made:

```
exec usp_FL_GetAllData @aFacilityCode='S'
```

Initially, I was assigning the value `Faccode` for my parameter in the `GetData` function but noticed this weird truncation, which is why I'm now hardcoding the value.

The only thing I could think of is that the SQL procedure defined the parameter as a `varchar(1)` but it's defined as 10 so I don't know why this is happening. `RunProcedure` is used in many places which do not exhibit this behavior.

What else could be causing this?

Comment: are you using string concatenation in your proc? if so, have you escaped any apostrophes (') correctly?

Comment: fyi: ADO.Net uses a feature called "Connection Pooling" that does not play well with trying to re-use the same connection object. The `RunProcedure()` method should create a new connection object for each call, and only re-use the same connection string. You really are much better off that way.

Comment: @DimUser No apostrophes or any characters like that. The expected SQL should be `exec usp_FL_GetAllData @aFacilityCode = 'SW29'`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I'll look into that, but this is a very old application I'm trying to modify so if that was never an issue before I'd be surprised if that's the issue now. This application used to use both Oracle and MS SQL, so I'm ripping out the Oracle code and replacing it with the MS SQL code.

Comment: Your code says `SqlDbType.VarChar` - where is the length? `varchar` defaults to `varchar(1)` in many cases.

Comment: For some reason, removing `ParameterDirection.Input` from `GetData` fixed my problem.

Comment: That sounds like I kicked the TV and the fridge started working again.

Comment: @AaronBertrand re: SqlDbType.VarChar defaulting to (1); I have this all over the place without a size. Any links to help me find out which of the "many cases" I have been lucky enough to avoid?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I am most interested in the connection object reuse. Any links where I can get more info? I have searched several times and asked on MSDN where I was told OK.

Comment: @Mary I don't have a link handy, but there's lots of info out there. Just be aware there are some serious down-sides to re-using the same connection object in your application, including side-stepping the connection pool which is there to help you, and creating a point of connection in your application that will prevent things like reading from a table to process data while you also update based on results at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

To see why removing the parameter direction from your constructor call solves the problem, take a look at the [list of constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) defined by the `SqlParameter` class. Note that there is no constructor that takes a parameter name, `SqlDbType`, and `ParameterDirection`; the constructor you're actually invoking is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hex23w80(v=vs.110).aspx), whose third parameter is the parameter size. Because the backing value of `ParameterDirection.Input` is 1, you are explicitly setting the size of the parameter to one character.

When you instead invoke a constructor that doesn't explicitly give a size, the object infers the size of the parameter from the value that you assign, as described in the [documentation for that property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ack; so simple and obvious. Don't know how I didn't pick up on that. The old Oracle code specified a `ParameterDirection` and when I changed this to a SqlParameter it didn't complain about that argument so I figured it was fine as is. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @sab669 I find it strange though that you don't get an exception in this case. If I insert something into a column by use of a normal query and it doesn't fit, I immediately get the dreaded `String or binary data would be truncated.` error. Not so much when it comes to stored procedures, though... Thanks for the answer anyway, solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

This makes a number of important changes to your code. It does address the parameter length issue, but you'll need to check if it actually helps.

```vb
's was not used, and ByRef is a code smell in .Net
Public Function GetData(ByVal Faccode As String) As DataSet
    Dim params As New SqlParameter("@aFacilityCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Faccode) Then Faccode = "SW29"
    params.Value = Faccode

    'Removed Try/Catch handler. It's NEVER a good idea to just swallow exceptions like that. Let the exception bubble up to higher level code that knows how to handle it.
    Return RunProcedure("usp_FL_GetAllData", "ContactData", params)    
End Function

'Note the change to SqlParameter. IDataParameter does not have a Length or Size property. That MIGHT be your problem.
'Also note the use of ParamArray... required changing the order of the arguments, but helped simplify code in the first function
Protected Overloads Function RunProcedure( _
  ByVal storedProcName As String, ByVal tableName As String, _
  ByVal ParamArray parameters() As SqlParameter) _
  As DataSet

    Dim dataSet As New dataSet 
    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection("string here"), _
          command As SqlCommand = BuildQueryCommand(storedProcName, parameters), _
          sqlDA As New SqlDataAdapter(command)

        command.Connection = myConnection
        sqlDA.Fill(dataSet, tableName) '.Fill() will open the connection for you if needed
    End Using
    Return dataSet
End Function

Private Function BuildQueryCommand( _
   ByVal storedProcName As String, _
  ByVal ParamArray parameters() As SqlParameter) _
  As SqlCommand

    Dim command As New SqlCommand(storedProcName)
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    If parameters IsNot Nothing Then command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters)    
    Return command    
End Function
```

Note these changes WILL likely impact other code in your application, but they are important.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, Joel, but unfortunately I fixed my issue: Removing the `ParameterDirection.Input` from `GetData` fixed the issue. I don't know why that fixed it, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the first line of `GetData` from this:

```
Dim params As SqlParameter() = {New SqlParameter("@aFacilityCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Input)}
```

To this:

```
Dim params As SqlParameter() = {New SqlParameter("@aFacilityCode", SqlDbType.VarChar)}
```

Fixed my issue. I'm not sure why, and if anyone knows I'd love to know why.

Comment: I posted a separate answer that explains this behavior.